# How to select one record in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.3

In our CakePHP application we have two tables:

- events
- event_dates

**events table**
[image: events table]

**event_dates table**
[image: event_dates table]

Select each event with its corresponding one date. That date will be nearest to the current date.

That means, there have 4 event's dates in `event_dates` table for `event_id` 1 (`event_id` is the foreign key). Then I want to select one row for event 1 which has `start_date = 2013-09-21`, because this is the nearest date with current date.

How can I do this?

This is my code:

`$events = $this->Event->find('all');`

But the above takes all dates with duplicate events records.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the main results by existence of sub-results than you have to use JOIN. Some thing like this, you can also set the order of data. This is just idea, please modify as per your requirement.

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'event_dates',
          'alias' => 'EventDate',
          'type' => 'INNER',
          'conditions' => array(
                'EventDate.event_id = Event.id'
                'EventDate.start_date <' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                 )
            )
        );

$options['fields'] = array('Event.id', 'Event.name', 'Event.address');

$events = $this->Event->find('all', $options);
```

For more details you can check http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

In `app/Model/EventDate.php`

add following:

```
public $hasOne = 'EventDate';
```

Now when you run `$this->Event->find('all');` the associated event_dates will be added automatically. If you have no results that means in your app model the recursivnes might be limited to contain just current model (which is always a good idea, as it speeds up whole system). In that case you can add `$this->Event->recursive = 1;` before the find method. or `public $recursive = -1;` or `$this->Event->find('all', array('recursive'=>1));`

You will find more in CakePHP documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html